# Removing Conditions In An Objective Function - Python

Tags: python, math, mathematical-optimization, mixed-integer-programming

My objective function is comprised of conditional variables, which is causing every re-run of my python script to have slightly different variable references. I need help re-writing my objective function so that there are no conditions in it, while still keeping the same problem/solution.

```
ObjectiveFunction = maximize(Σ(Ψ_[p, r] * (x_bar[p, r] + c[p, r]) for p in P for r in R))
```

where:

- p is a player
- r is the round
- Ψ is a dictionary ( Dict[Tuple[str, int], int] ) representing the score of player p in round r
- x_bar is a binary variable ( x_bar := (p, r) ) of whether a player is counted as scoring (part of the team) in round r
- c is a binary variable ( c := (p, r) ) representing a captain who has a doubled score in round r

I have looked at several similar questions, but have had no luck applying their answers to my problem.
They are:

- [If condition in Cplex objective function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50065233/if-condition-in-cplex-objective-function)
- [Pyomo and conditional objective function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46357217/pyomo-and-conditional-objective-function)
- [How can I model `if` conditionals in Gurobi Python Objective Function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56738865/how-can-i-model-if-conditionals-in-gurobi-python-objective-function)

Thank you for taking the time to read this and help me. It truly means a lot!

Comment: I don't see the conditions in the objective function you wrote??

Comment: Note that in general, https://or.stackexchange.com is a better resource than https://stackoverflow.com when it comes to rewriting an objective function.

Comment: Thank you for your advice Stef